# django-hitcount not recording ip adresses in hit

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-migrations, hit-count

So, i'm using django-hitcount to keep track of user hits in my application. the application uses uuid as primary key for id of the books. so, i did a little modification to the django-hitcount code from [here](https://github.com/thornomad/django-hitcount/tree/fcf399698455d656810a9456ccd0b42a8290969f). the exact new version isnt compatible so i used it upto a specific commit. the forked repo is [here](https://github.com/Aneemes/django-hitcount). I only changed the object_pk on the hitcountbase model to uuid and removed the previous id which was used as a primary key.
You can check the commit in [here](https://github.com/Aneemes/django-hitcount/commits/develop)
Running it on my project it is not recording the ip addresses of the hits and putting in the default 10.0.0.1 ip address on every data it tracks.
Did I miss to change something while making it work with uuid?